# UIBezierPath Respond to Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath, bezier

I was trying to add a gesture responder to a UIBezierPath, but it was giving me an error.

So I am wondering.. is it possible to add a gesture responder to a UIBezierPath object?

For example, I have a stroked line and I want to change one of the line's point position by dragging that said point somewhere else inside the screen... can you give me some advice on how would I be able to do that? (can't find a relevant answer to my question in the internet so I thought it's better if I asked) Or a link close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to add a gesture responder to a UIBezierPath object

No. You can only add a gesture recognizer to a UIView. A UIBezierPath is not a UIView.

But you can add a gesture recognizer to a UIView that *draws* a UIBezierPath. And you can respond to the gesture by changing the path and drawing again.